# Задать переменные из ссылки без формы через php ($_GET)

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, form, submit

Я только начинаю изучать веб. Делаю страницу с 1 продуктом на php.
На главной имеется несколько опций цвета, строка с количеством и кнопка, открывающая всплывающую форму-post, в которой вводятся ФИО и эмейл.
По нажатию submit-кнопки во всплывающей форме мне на почту приходит письмо, в котором я вижу ФИО и эмейл покупателя, но не вижу выбранный цвет и количество. Как получить эти параметры?

Подозреваю, что можно сделать, чтобы при выборе нужного цвета в адресную строку добавлялся параметр, например ?color=red, а в основной форме задать переменную $_GET['color']. Но похоже, что при сабмите формы открывается ссылка на ее form.php, и ?color=red пропадает из адресной строки.
И если это почти правильно, то как быть с количеством товара? Как переменной задать значение из html/java?

ссылка на сайт - ekosamoe.ru

form.php:

```
$qty = $_GET['qty'];
$color = $_GET['color'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];

mail($mailTo, $name, $qty, $color);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В HTML-формах значения всех полей кодируются одинаково. Если у формы указан `method="get"`, то поля засунутся в query запроса (в php будут доступны в массиве `$_GET`), если указать `method="post"`, то все данные отправятся в теле запроса (и будут доступны через $_POST).

Хотя можно самостоятельно сформировать запрос и поместить часть значений в query, а часть в тело запроса, делать этого скорее всего не надо. В большинстве случаев правильно было бы предпочесть только один способ.

В вашем случае, надо добавить в форму поля `qty` и `color`. Эти поля могут быть скрытыми (`type="hidden"`). После добавления этих полей в форму, их значения будут доступны через $_POST: `$_POST['qty']` и `$_POST['color']`.

Чтобы установить значения этих полей в форме автоматически из значений переданных в query, можно написать такой код в шаблоне формы:

```
<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['qty']) ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="color" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['color']) ?>">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает! Попробовал вручную вписать нужный адрес с параметрами и форма их подхватывает. Но как сделать, чтобы значение параметров цвета и количества автоматически добавлялись в адресную строку без кнопки и перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: @Александр Я тогда не понял ваш вопрос. Если вы хотите не перезагружать страницу после выбора цвета и количества, то вам просто надо задать параметры формы с помощью js. Получите значения из поля, в котором вводили значения и установите их в форме.